# I want to upload some data to my database but the method returns me null

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I'm making a game and in this method i want to save the game to my database. the gamename, the players, the cardstacks and the player who's turn it is, has to be uploaded to the database.
However, this method returns me always null and there is no data in my table in the database.
How can i make this work?

There are no problems with the connection because another method who gets cards out of the database works.

java

```
public void slaSpelOp(String spelnaam, String spelers, String kerkerstapel, String schatstapel, String spelerAanBeurt) {

    try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(Connectie.URL, Connectie.USERNAME, Connectie.PASSWORD)) {
        PreparedStatement query = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO ID222177_g08.Spel (naam, spelers, kerkerstapel, schatstapel, spelerAanBeurt)"
                + "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

        query.setString(1, spelnaam);
        query.setString(2, spelers);
        query.setString(3, kerkerstapel);
        query.setString(4, schatstapel);
        query.setString(5, spelerAanBeurt);

        query.close();

        query.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
}
```

the data has to be in the database, now i get nothing

Comment: Does the account definitely have write permissions on the DB?

Comment: Yes definitely sure

Comment: Instead of throwing the error, print it out using `System.out.println(ex.tostring());`

Comment: Is that try block syntactically correct? My java is rusty but it looks wrong to me

Comment: @Sedrick i did what you say, but it returns me null. so does that mean that the sqlexception isn't even reached?

Comment: @RiggsFolly i used it before in another method to retrieve some data in the same and it worked.

Comment: If you are using SQL, use MySQL Workbench or something similar to check your queries against the database. That's what I do if I have problems. If you are using SQLite, use DB Browser for SQLite.

Comment: It's unclear what **method** returns you null. Did you mean that you get 0(zero) records when select from that table after insert is done? Or that select query gives you a record with all columns set to `NULL`. Clarification is required

Answer (score 1):

You need to close the query After executeUpdate. Dont close the query before executeUpdate.

**Fixed code**:

```
public void slaSpelOp(String spelnaam, String spelers, String kerkerstapel, String schatstapel, String spelerAanBeurt) {

try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(Connectie.URL, Connectie.USERNAME, Connectie.PASSWORD)) {
    PreparedStatement query = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO ID222177_g08.Spel (naam, spelers, kerkerstapel, schatstapel, spelerAanBeurt)"
            + "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

    query.setString(1, spelnaam);
    query.setString(2, spelers);
    query.setString(3, kerkerstapel);
    query.setString(4, schatstapel);
    query.setString(5, spelerAanBeurt);

    query.executeUpdate();

    query.close(); // AFTER executeUpdate

} catch (SQLException ex) {
    throw new RuntimeException(ex);
}
}
```

**NOTE:** You can use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) for query object too like you did for conn object so you don't have to close the query object manually.

Comment: The try-with-resources being: `try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(Connectie.URL, Connectie.USERNAME, Connectie.PASSWORD); PreparedStatement query = conn.prepareStatement(...)) {`

Comment: @JoopEggen: try ( PreparedStatement query = conn.prepareStatement()) { ... }